# Yarvik TAB doesn't show up in Eclipse on Ubuntu

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu-12.04

I have developped an Android app. When I connect to a phone on the USB port, I can run the App on the phone and debug the App.

However if I connect to a Yarvik TAB461EUK, with USB connect and allow debugging switched on on the device, it doesn show up in Elipse. Outside Eclipse is shows up as "TAB461" USB device (the external storage of the TAB) and another "2,0 GB filesystem".

Why does it work with the phone and not with the tablet?

Platform info: PC: Eclipse 3.7.2, Ubuntu 12.04; Tablet: Yarvik TAB461EUK, Android 4.0.3; Phone: HTC-HD2, ROM Android 2.3

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my Xenta Tab9-200. The USB debug icon was shown in the notification area but neither Eclipse nor `adb devices` showed the tablet.
I solved the problem by editing my `~/.android/adb_usb.ini` file and adding a vendor id for Rockchip and restarting the adb:

```
echo 0x2207 >> adb_usb.ini
sudo adb kill-server
sudo adb start-server
```

The solution came from the Yarvik support forum:
http://forum.yarvik.com/showthread.php?4270-Xenta-Driver-for-eclipse-connection